# How to make Link in oracle apex viewed by a user and not for an other user

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm using Oracle APEX 4.2

I have one Text area item.

I would like to make it as a link for a user A and just display it for the user B.

For example: the user A can click on it. the user B can't do it.

Any ideas

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

for similar issues, i am creating 2 displays on the page and managing the display of them on page by using "Conditions" Parameter.

with appropiate condition setting  you can show clickable display to user A and not B,
and display read only one to User B and not User A

Comment: Thanks for the idea. in fact, this is what I do. But what to do if we have 100+  items and bottons ?

Comment: i am assuming you are using the textarea as readonly for display puprose? how do you manage the links in textarea data? are you generating with a query or other users are typing them within text ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was confused with type of items: it's not a Text area. it's a Display Only element. Yes I generate the link with a select query with html code for example: 'SELECT <a href="MyLink">COLUMN</a> FROM MyTable;'

Comment: i am assuming that your links like below 'this is <a href=google.com>link</a>' in a database row, i know it is not a proper way but if you remove "href=" keyword in hyperlink link would be disabled. you may use a code as follows: select 
CASE USER_ID

   WHEN 'A' THEN DB_FIELD
   WHEN 'B' THEN REPLACE(DB_FIELD,'href=','')
   
   ELSE NULL

END

from your_table

Comment: sorry i didnt see your code. using case statement in your select query would work. like select 

CASE USER_ID

   WHEN 'A' THEN '<a href="MyLink">'||COLUMN||'</a>'
   WHEN 'B' THEN COLUMN
   
   ELSE NULL

END

from your_table

Comment: Thank you. I will try this method and let you know if there is issue

Comment: please check the internet for "oracle select case statement" tutorials. also there is different usages and good examples